# Has MyBatis ever been able to cast java Calendar?

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

Two days ago I wrote this piece of program to access database, and it's been running fine. It contains some actions about searching datas with TIME as a parameter. In db, which in my case, pgsql, it's timestamp. As I'm using MyBatis, I checked on MyBatis website, and I specificly remember it say MyBatis will cast java.util.Date **AND** Calendar to timestamp, and since Calendar is the easy one to calculate, that's the one I chose.
Then about 3 hours earlier, my program crashed after already been writing 20k lines of data into my database. The error message are like this:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='calendar', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.GregorianCalendar. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

First I thought it was a null pointer thing, so natually I pulled it from the cloud server and run it locally with debugs on, the error remains the same.

```
Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.GregorianCalendar. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

Finally I realized it was a casting issue, MyBatis refuses to use Calendar as paramter for timestamp, at least not without further configuration.
Then I checked [MyBatis website](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#:%7E:text=Iterator-,typeHandlers,-Whenever%20MyBatis%20sets), but there was no mentioning of Calendar whatsoever.

The problem itself is quite simply solved, call the getTime() to get the Date to replace ALL THOSE CALENDARS.
But the whole thing still throws me off.
Does anyone remember if MyBatis have ever been able to cast Calendar? Or do I need medical attention about my memory impairment?

Comment: Calendar can theoretically be used, but it's mostly obsolete nowadays. Use LocalDate, LocalTime, and all the java.time classes. All engines now support it (since 2018 probably).

Answer (score 0):

I'm ditching this question. But if you're here for the same reason, don't look into it, change the Calendar to Date and move on. It's NOT WORTH thinking about it.

Comment: Might be even better to replace `Calendar` / `Date` with something from the `java.time` package.

Comment: Yes I shoud've done that. I might be the only person who uses Calendar on java 17.